# Asp.net HttpModule for tracking user and hits

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a need to record user hits and user_agent hitting multiple web applications.  I have currently creating http module to record request.servervariables (including user_agent).

This currently records every request from the site, i.e. a page with css would be counted as 2 .  What is the best way I can modify so that I record only once for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a cookie and check is the cookie exists before recording the information